# How Can I Save An Image To An iPhone Photo Gallery Using PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova

I am creating a PhoneGap app for the iPhone that displays a gallery of images. Some images are included with the project installation, and some are from the web. When a user clicks on an image, I would like them to be able to save the image to an iPhone photo gallery (Photos). Originally, I would have liked the app to let the user set the image as wallpaper, but found that it would be extremely difficult or impossible.

I could only find one solution for saving the image using PhoneGap and Objective C, but the PhoneGap solution contained the class PhoneGapCommand which is deprecated. I tried using PGPlugin, but could not get the code to work.

I am hoping that someone out there might have a current PhoneGap solution that can perform this task, or if anyone could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: you can refer http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/1097750723/phonegap-plugin-for-downloading-url?ca81a6f8

Comment: Thank you for the link, Maulik. The code you provided saves to the documents folder for the application, however, I am looking for a way to save to Photos, so that the user can access the photo after it is saved.

Comment: Found part of the solution. It took me forever to find this code, because the original download was broken. The code is updated for the current version of PhoneGap:

https://github.com/khamer/phonegap-plugins-official/tree/master/iPhone/SaveImage

I could use help implementing it. I added the Objective C classes under the classes folder in the project where the AppDelegate files are. I added the javascript file under the www folder.

I added a call to the javascript file in index.html, and tried to call the SaveImage function in the onclick of an anchor tag, but I couldn't get the code to run.

Comment: the plugin files (.h and .m) will go in the Plugins folder, not Classes.

Comment: also u would have to add an entry to the plist for the plugin

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but it took me a day to figure this out since this example is no longer applicable to the new version of Cordova. I am currently using version 2.5.0, so I thought I'd share this so others would not have to go through the pain I did.

To save an image, you'll have to write your own plug-in. Here are the steps:

1. Open your Cordova XCODE project and edit config.xml. Add an entry for the plugin you'll be creating.

"name" is the JavaScript namespace you'll be using and "value" is the Objective-C class name.

1. In your XCODE project, locate the "Plugins" group. Right click it and select "New File..." from the context menu. Add a new class file "MySaveImageToAlbum". It should be inherited from CDVPlugin.
2. Below are the codes for the header and the implementation files:

   // MySaveImageToAlbum.h
       #import

   ```
   @interface MySaveImageToAlbum : CDVPlugin
    - (void)saveImageToAlbum:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
   @end
   ```

   // MySaveImageToAlbum.m
       #import "CDVSaveImageToAlbum.h"

   ```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


   @implementation MySaveImageToAlbum

   - (void)saveImageToAlbum:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
   {
       CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[command.arguments objectAtIndex:0]];
       NSData *args = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];


       if (args != nil && [args length] > 0) {

           @try
           {
               UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:args];
               NSData *imgdata = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
               UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageWithData:imgdata];
               UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image2, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);


               pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"success"];
               [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
           }
           @catch (NSException *exception) {
               pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR];
               [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
           }

       } else {
           pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR];
           [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
       }

   }


   - (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
     contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
   {
       // Was there an error?
       if (error != NULL)
       {
           // Show error message...

       }
       else  // No errors
       {
           // Show message image successfully saved

       }
   }


   @end
   ```
3. Next, you'll need to create a javascript file that calls this native code. Here's the code:

   var SaveImageToAlbum = 
      {
        saveImageToAlbum: function(successCallback,errorCallback,args)
     {
               cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "SaveImageToAlbum", "saveImageToAlbum", [args]);
           }
       };
4. Make a reference to the JavaScript created in no.4 in your index.html. Suppose you have a canvas and you want to save it as an image to the camera roll, you can use its "toDataURL()" function to return a base64 PNG data. You can then call the saveImageToAlbum function and pass this as a parameter like this:

   SaveImageToAlbum.saveImageToAlbum(function(e){
                                                           navigator.notification.alert("Image has been successfully saved in the Photo Album.", null, "Image saved!");
                                                       },
                                                        function(e){
                                                           navigator.notification.alert("Image could not be saved in the Photo Album.", null, "Save error!");
                                                        },
                                                        canvas.toDataURL());

That's it!

Hope you enjoy...

Regards,
Antonio C. Logarta III

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own. I was able to use Jesse MacFadyen's ImageHelper.

http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/ea7ee31887b2f610/fe2c0b127cf51e7a

http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/tree/browse_frm/thread/8aeefbb9421f1b81/94963d9742b0738f?hide_quotes=no

When I first implemented this, I had all the code right, but I didn't have ImageHelper added as an entry in the PhoneGap.plist plugins section. I also changed the deprecated PhoneGapCommand to PGPlugin.