# Saving an image to Iphone Photo Gallery with Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'd like to be able to programmatically save an image from a page to the Iphone Photo Gallery with my phonegap app. (Much like how you can save an image by longpressing it an then 'Save Image' in iOS safari)

Is there a way to do this with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following post might resolve your problem:

[How Can I Save An Image To An iPhone Photo Gallery Using PhoneGap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663890/how-can-i-save-an-image-to-an-iphone-photo-gallery-using-phonegap)

### Edit

[FileTransfer.download()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer_download) is another way to save images locally, check the Phonegap doc [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) to get more options on that.

Comment: Great. But I don't quite see how it would work without capturing the image first. I want to save an image which is on the page.

Comment: yes sorry i misunderstood the question, i have updated the new link which might help

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe that post didn't turn up when I searched for 'save image [phonegap]'